# How to generate year sequence in a Qlikview table?

Tags: qlikview

I would like to have one table in Qlikview with Year values stored in it. They should start from 2000 and end with the latest year (i.e. 2014).

I want to make it dynamic, so that next year, the values would be till 2015. How do I go about it?

P.S.
I tried following but it didn't work.

SET vInitYear = 2000;

YearSequence:
LOAD vInitYear AS YearSeq AutoGenerate(Year(Today));

Comment: Autogenerate takes parameter for the number of rows to create, RowNo() can be used to count the number of records you created, so if you change your code to this it would work:

Comment: YearSequence: 
LOAD $(vInitYear)+RowNo() AS YearSeq  AutoGenerate(  Year(Today())-$(vInitYear) );

Comment: @seebach: Actually, in my opinion your comment here is a better answer than your other one - it is nice and tidy and only requires one variable and no loops - good work!

Comment: @Ketan: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer so that other users can benefit from it.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the job...

```
FOR i = 0 to 15
  LET NewDate = YEAR(UTC())-i;
  LOAD * INLINE [
    MyYear
    $(NewDate)
  ];    
NEXT i
```

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR y = 2000 to Year(today())

Years:
LOAD $(y) as Year
Autogenerate 1; 

NEXT y
```